# RAILS: Couldn't find Manufacturer with ID=2 for Frame with ID=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-5

**Bicycle_params:**

```
<ActionController::Parameters { "frame_attributes"=>

<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"ASD", "manufacturer_attributes"=>

<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>2, "title"=>"Rock Shox"} permitted:

 true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

**What is happening:**

I have form where you can choose bicycle frame manufacturer and enter name of the fork model in the `text_field`. If manufacturer is choosed from list, it set's `param[:bicycle][:frame_attributes][:manufacturer_attributes][:id]` if not - creates new manufacturer based on title you provided.

So, when i type name of manufacturer (to create frame AND new manufacturer) - everything is fine. **BUT** when i choose manufacturer from the list, i get an

**Error:**

```
Couldn't find Manufacturer with ID=2 for Frame with ID=
```

Comment: can u just post `server log`

Comment: @7urkm3n, http://pastebin.com/CUEp0FEJ

Comment: can u post all of that like after triggering it, it will start with POST.

Comment: @7urkm3n, i think this could help you more to understand the problem http://pastebin.com/3bZAtKUk